# How to configure ThreadPoolExecutor to limit number of threads

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpoolexecutor

Before I get into details, I want to say that I have everything working using threads. I want to use ThreadPoolExecutor. I could not understand how ThreadPoolExecutor works in my case.

I have an xml file. I wrote code that parses this xml file and when the parser parses through a pre defined end element tag, I put the element on a queue.

I start 4 threads that listens to the queue in the startDocument method.

```
public void startDocument()
    {
        String queueName = getQueueName();
        messageSendRecieve = new MessageSendRecieve( queueName );
        int maxProcessorThreads = 4;
        recieveThread = new RecieveThread[maxProcessorThreads];
        for( int i = 0; i < maxProcessorThreads; i++ )
        {
            recieveThread[i] = new recieveThread ( queueName,new String( "" + ( i + 1 ) ),                                                                   outputFileName,
                                                                          jobId );
        recieveThread[i].start();
        }
    }
```

and in endElement method

```
 public void endElement( String namespaceURI, String localName, String qName ) throws SAXException
    {

        if( PRODUCT.equals( localName ) )
        {
            totalProducts++;
            productXML.append( NODEENDSTARTTAG ).append( localName ).append( NODEEND );
           messageSendRecieve.putMessage( productXML.toString() );
        }
}
```

on the receiving side, each of my 4 threads create a new file, listens to the queue, does some processing and finally writes the output to it. Finally, my main Thread will merge all 4 output files into 1 file.

I want to convert this process using ThreadPoolExecutor, I went through examples in internet and everywhere I see

```
executor.execute(new RecieveThread(threadCounter.toString()));
```

My question is how will ThreadPoolExecutor fit in my case? If I have an xml file with 1000 products, will ThreadPoolExecutor creates 1000 threads and each thread creating an output file (1000 files)?

Comment: Please read the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) before asking. I think it explains perfectly what you're asking. If not, please state what you don't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> executor.execute(new RecieveThread(threadCounter.toString()));

No, this isn't how the `ExecutorService` classes work.  You are submitting a thread as if it is a `Runnable`.  So you end up with a `Thread` class that actually isn't a thread.  The pool threads are just calling the `RecieveThread.run()` method.

You should submit your small `Runnable` or `Callable` classes to the `ExecutorService` thread-pool instead.  Maybe a "task" to submit to the `ExecutorService` is a `MessageSendRecieve`?  It's hard to tell from your code.

For example, he's a small simple job class that I use as an example:

```
public class MyJob implements Runnable {
    // you can construct your jobs and pass in context for them if necessary
    public MyJob(String someContext) {
        ...
    }
    public void run() {
        // process the small job
    }
}
```

The threads are started by the `ExecutorService` and each one of them dequeue one of the jobs from an internal queue and call `run()` on them in turn.

You might want to read the [docs about `ExecutorService` and friends](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/exinter.html).